# Remove background colour from material

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I want to have my material base colour a transparent to let the image below show through. At the moment highlited with pink circles the colour is black.
I am adding an image texture to the material which i want to be visible.
Is this possible?[image]

Comment: Can't see any image, did you forget to add a reference?

Comment: Does image show up now? Trying to edit post

Comment: So you are trying to get rid of the black around the numbers right? Also, does your image texture have an alpha channel?

Comment: Yes i am unwrapping the black section and adding an image to that. But i dont want the black part of the unwrapped material to show.

Comment: You can use the search box at the top of the page to find answers to questions that are commonly asked: [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447)

Comment: Thanks, i did search that but that is not what i was trying to do which is why i asked the question :p

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the background color, you can set up your nodes like this:

[image]

This will work if you have an alpha channel in your png. Otherwise, you can do something like this to remove the black from the image:

[image]
This will make everything with a value of less than 0.001 (in other words black) transparent. If you are using eevee, you will have to change the blend mode to alpha blend and uncheck "Show Backface" in the material settings to make things actually transparent:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you it does work, just had to change to Alpha blend in the material properties. Thanks for your help :)